# Cómo crear un widget flotante en android que se muestre al salir de la aplicación que permita regresar a la misma

Tags: android, android-studio, botón

Quisiera saber como crear un widget flotante que aparezca al momento de salir de la aplicacion me permita regresar a la misma,como lo tiene la aplicación de uber drive o flygps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ese botón, se genera con un `Servicio` de android, agregando un `View` al `WindowsManager`.

```
package com.example.chatheads;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;

//Importante extender de service
public class ChatHeadService extends Service {


    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private ImageView chatHead;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //Obtenemos la instancia de WindowsManager
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        //Instanciamos el objeto que queremos adjuntar a WindowsManager
        chatHead = new ImageView(this);
        chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.face1);

        //Aplicamos parametros que necesitemos
        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        //Posicion donde queremos que se acople
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;

        //TouchListener para mover el elemento por la pantalla
        chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        initialX = params.x;
                        initialY = params.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        params.x = initialX
                                + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        params.y = initialY
                                + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        //Acoplamos el elemento a la pantalla
        windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (chatHead != null)
            windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

También sera necesario agregar al manifest el permiso de `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

Y ademas agregar el servicio al manifest

```
<service android:name="com.example.chatheads.ChatHeadService">
```

Con este ejemplo básico te generaría un circulo abajo a la izquierda con la imagen que tu le pongas, luego todo es gestionar el `OnTouchListener` para que vuelva a la aplicación, y muy importante gestionar los `OnDestroy`, `OnResume`, `OnPause` etc, para matar y reactivar el servicio.

[Aqui](http://androidsrc.net/facebook-chat-like-floating-chat-heads/) la fuente de información